# Как распарсить в PHP этот массив?

Tags: php, массивы

Этот массив взят из недр "Google". Надо парсить подобные строки в "PHP"-массивы; кроме того, необходима и обратная возможность создания подобных строк из массивов.

```
[1,"[\"gansry\",,[[[\"answer\",\"00beebc9c62970b20004fa4b61b0b175\",[\"post\",\"Go to Settings , then you will get option to clear browser cache memory, there select cookies too. That will remove all history from your browser.\\r\\n\\r\\nIf you are using Chrom then go to\\r\\n\\r\\nchrome://history/\\r\\n\\r\\nnow here you will get clear browsing data.\",[1401101575,1401101575303541]\n,,[\"16654934222362450494\",\"Shaon\",,0,13,1,[]\n,,51]\n,\"Go to Settings , then you will get option to clear browser cache memory, there select cookies too. That will remove all history from your browser.\\u003cbr\\u003e\\u003cbr\\u003eIf you are using Chrom then go to\\u003cbr\\u003e\\u003cbr\\u003echrome://history/\\u003cbr\\u003e\\u003cbr\\u003enow here you will get clear browsing data.\"]\n,[]\n,\"00beebc9c62970b2\",1,1]\n,[1,0,0]\n,[4]\n]\n,[[\"answer\",\"00beebc9c62970b20004fa83993e2a43\",[\"post\",\"Please check this link then you can easily remove cookies from any browser\\r\\nhttp://www.wikihow.com/Clear-Your-Browser%27s-Cookies\",[1401343025,1401343025490499]\n,,[\"08871022889263261958\",\"Shammi\",,0,10,1,[]\n,,80]\n,\"Please check this link then you can easily remove cookies from any browser\\u003cbr\\u003ehttp://www.wikihow.com/Clear-Your-Browser%27s-Cookies\"]\n,[]\n,\"00beebc9c62970b2\",,1]\n,[0,0,0]\n,[4]\n]\n]\n,0,[]\n]\n"]
```

Заранее благодарю.

Comment: Первый шаг — это `json_decode()` — получается массив из двух элементов: единица и длинная строка. В ней уже идут структуры похожие на json, но не совсем. Например, встречаются пропущенные значения - две запятые подряд. Может, если вместо них написать `,null,`, получится валидный JSON?

Comment: А еще заменить символы новой строки на "\\n"

Comment: главное понять что мешает сделать это, может быть готовую выдачу с экранами \" мешает парсить, так значит может пропустить через replace "\ на "" а после уж и JSON.parse. Нет? А там уж и в Array перекрутить жи можно через циклы теж самые, друг ты чаво

Comment: Ага, валидный JSON получается после простой замены `,,` на `,'',`, больше ничего трогать и не нужно. Ну разве что добавить кавычки, чтобы всю строку захватить, с первой `[1` и последней скобкой. То есть:

    $s = "[1,[\"gansry\"...\n]";
    $s = str_replace( ",,", ",'',", $s );
    $s = json_decode( $s );
    print_r( $s );

Но всё равно правильный путь - спросить у самого гугла. Раз это их потроха, наверняка где-то и техописание есть.

Comment: Это объект google.

var d=eval('('+OBJECT+')');// вместо OBJECT вставьте ваш текст
alertObj(d);

function alertObj(obj) { 
    var str = ""; 
    for(k in obj) { 
        str += k+": "+ obj[k]+"\r\n"; 
    } 
    alert(str);
}

Comment: @FrancNet, вы думаете, что ваш комментарий хоть что-то проясняет? Наоборот, вызывает ещё больше вопросов: какой именно из многочисленных "объектов гугла", для какого API, где описан и т.д.

Comment: ну так хоть человек структуру увидит, а там глядишь и мысли появятся, сам как то JSON ответы сервака разбирал, помогло ...

Comment: В общем, что-то жалкое вроде как получилось сделать:

[code]$t=str_replace("\\\"","\"",$t);
$t=str_replace("\\n","",$t);
$t=str_replace(",,",",null,",$t);
eval("\$arr=".$t.";");
var_dump($arr); exit;[/code]

Правда, то, что получается, поистине ужасно.

Comment: Зачем столько замен, если для JSON достаточно одной?

Comment: Одному мне кажется, что это не вопрос "как сделать", а просьба "сделайте"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это [JSON](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) массив. Берите любой JSON парсер и парсите его в массив JavaScript объектов. Ну и обратно аналогично - создаете JavaScript объекты и генерируете из них JSON массивы.